# Find the position of string in a list in Neo4j, Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How would i find the index value of a string within a list - for example

```
WITH split ("what is porsche",' ')
```

how would I find the position of 'porsche' as 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the position would be 2 as we generally start from 0 in CS.

This is a one liner :

```
WITH split ("what is porsche",' ') AS spl
RETURN [x IN range(0,size(spl)-1) WHERE spl[x] = "porsche"][0]
```

Returns `2`

```
WITH split ("what is porsche",' ') AS spl
RETURN [x IN range(0,size(spl)-1) WHERE spl[x] = "is"][0]
```

Returns `1`

Answer (score 3):

Cypher does not have an `IndexOf-like` function natively. But you can install [APOC Procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and use the function `apoc.coll.indexOf`, like this:

```
WITH split ("what is porsche",' ') AS list
RETURN apoc.coll.indexOf(list, 'porsche')
```

The result will be:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════╕
│"apoc.coll.indexOf(list, 'porsche')"│
╞════════════════════════════════════╡
│2                                   │
└────────────────────────────────────┘
```

*Note: The result is 2 because indexes starts at 0.*

Note 2: Remember to install APOC Procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [version compatibility matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).

**EDIT:**

One alternative approach without using APOC Procedures, using [size()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-size), [reduce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) and [range()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-range) functions with [CASE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#query-syntax-case) expression:

```
WITH split ("what is porsche",' ') AS list
WITH list, range(0, size(list) - 1) AS indexes
WITH reduce(acc=-1, index IN indexes |
    CASE WHEN list[index] = 'porsch' THEN index ELSE acc + 0 END
) as reduction
RETURN reduction
```

In case the index is not found then -1 will return.

Comment: I was also working on providing a solution in vanilla Cypher with list comprehensions, but you beat me to it. Great!

Answer (score 2):

As Bruno says, APOC is the right call for this but if for some reason you wanted to find the position without APOC you could go through the following rigamarole...

```
WITH split("what is porsche",' ') AS porsche_strings
UNWIND range(0,size(porsche_strings)-1) AS idx
WITH CASE
  WHEN porsche_strings[idx] = 'porsche' THEN idx + 1
END AS position
RETURN collect(position) AS positions
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for implementing this in plain Cypher:

```
WITH 'porsche' AS needle, 'what is porsche' AS haystack
WITH needle, split(haystack, ' ') AS words
WITH needle, [i IN range(0, length(words)-1) | [i, words[i]]] AS word
WITH filter(w IN word WHERE w[1] = needle) AS res
RETURN coalesce(res[0][0], -1)
```

Comment: Both alternatives were brilliant; however the first one by Bruno took 1ms and the second took 18 ms. Again, I am very impressed!

Comment: Thanks for upvoting and accepting this, but I don't think this should be the accepted answer :-). Use APOC if you can.